# How long was Shi-woon trained by Goomoonryong?

Tags: the-breaker

In [The Breaker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Breaker_%28manhwa%29), how long was Shi-woon under the tutelage of Goomoonryong? I was under the impression that it was only for a few weeks most of which were spent improving his stamina. As far as I can remember, he was only taught some basic techniques. Yet, he keeps pulling new *Murim* tricks out of the bag on a regular basis.

Answer (score 2):

He spent only few weeks with the Goomoonryong where:

- he got stamina training, but actually not that much
- he got the medicine that actually increased his stamina and his ki
- from that, he got a lot of training on how to circulate his ki around
- the soul crushing technique was shown to him once
- the 4 different foot techniques were shown to him once each
- and the most important, at the end of the breaker, he gave him a smart phone with many videos to show him new techniques and random advice.

On top of that, he was shown some techniques only once, and he managed to replicate them, although they were supposed to be difficult. So in fight, we can assume he can do the same. Shi woon is a prodigy.

In the breaker new waves, even in a second state (under the black origin thingy), during the school arc, against the SUC, when facing the lone wolf, he managed to replicate the techniques easily, even in a state where he can't even think.

So to summarize, some solid basic trainings, then many videos to improve by himself on top of the fact that he is a prodigy.

Also, with the inner training technique he received in the breaker new wave, he is able to train in his mind, so it might make things easier to try new things.

Answer (score 0):

Are we just talking about The Breaker? or is New Waves included?

Here's info on The Breaker exclusively:

Actually, it was more than a few weeks. I would say... 1½ to 2 months? Maybe more. Because you must account for the time that was spent:

- When Shi-Woon tries to get stronger with his weak
- Getting stronger through that medicinal ball thing that was given to him and enhanced his strength and ki
- His first few weeks of stamina training
- Then Chun-Woo (Goomoonryong) demonstrates the Soul-Crushing Strike
- And finally, before Goomoonryong leaves, he demonstrates the foot technique once

Anything else that is demonstrated by Shi-Woon is all from either him being an abnormal prodigy where he saw something once and understood it perfectly. OR from him adapting what was taught to him originally.

Hopefully that answered your question.

By the way, I highly recommend The Breaker: New Waves

Comment: you can include all the videos he left in shi-woon's mobile which he studies sometimes. in that video goomoonryong taught him the black origin thing.